# Can't fully delete first object in array returned by Fetch Request (Core Data)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm writing a time tracking app and when I delete the first section of time logged, it removes from tableView on two view controllers (as expected) but the time logged in the "total duration for today" area doesn't subtract the deleted time. This only occurs at the first index, the rest works as expected.

Code for deleting the object:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle:   
UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  if editingStyle == .Delete {
  var historyToSubtract =   
  fetchController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! History
   MainViewController().calculateDeletedDurationForToday(historyToSubtract)
```

Code in MainViewController for subtracting the deleted duration:

```
func calculateDeletedDurationForToday(historyToSubtract: History?) -> NSInteger {
    var todaysActivitiesArray = CoreDataHandler.sharedInstance.fetchCoreDataForTodayActivities()
    var totalDuration = MainViewController().calculateTotalDurationForToday()
    if todaysActivitiesArray.count < 1 {
        totalDuration = 0
    }
    else {
        totalDuration = totalDuration - Int(historyToSubtract!.duration!)
    }
    print(todaysActivitiesArray)
    print(totalDuration)
    CoreDataHandler.sharedInstance.deleteObject(historyToSubtract as! NSManagedObject)
    CoreDataHandler.sharedInstance.saveContext()

    return totalDuration

}
```

Code to fetch core data for today (todaysActivitiesArray):

```
func fetchCoreDataForTodayActivities() -> [History] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entityDescription =   
NSEntityDescription.entityForName("History", inManagedObjectContext: 
self.backgroundManagedObjectContext)
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription

    let dateDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "startDate", ascending: 
false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateDescriptor]

    let startDate = NSDate.dateByMovingToBeginningOfDay()
    let endDate = NSDate.dateByMovingToEndOfDay()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(startDate >= %@) AND 
(startDate <= %@)", startDate, endDate)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    return (fetchCoreDataWithFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [History])
}
```

I was previously getting an error that it was trying to access index 0 on an empty array, so I believe the fetchCoreDataForTodayActivities() is doing something weird for the first index but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I doubt that the generic instance`MainViewController()` ever works. Is`MainViewController`designed in the storyboard?

Comment: @vadian yes, it is. What do you suggest instead?

Comment: You need the real reference of that controller (`IBOutlet` or a delegate). The initializer `MainViewController()` creates always a brand new instance which is **never** the controller in the storyboard.